# Getting DOM in console linux application using WebKit or something else

Tags: linux, dom, webkit, console, chromium

I want get DOM of webiste after it is loaded(after all javascript scripts are executed) using WebKit or other engine in console linux application without any GUI

Is there any possibility to do it?

Best regards

Comment: You should probably say what language you're using. The `linux` and `console` tags make it look like shell scripting, but that's probably not the right job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.phantomjs.org/ a headless WebKit with JavaScript API.

Answer (score 0):

konqueror and other KDE applications expose much of their functionality via DBUS interfaces, so you may be able to script something launching a konqueror instance and then using `qdbus` to control it.